# Call method dynamically based on variable name

Tags: xtext, xbase

I currently have a generated XBase object with some method names:

`get_0()`, `get_1()`, `get_...()`, `get_50()`

Now I'd like to call them with a loop instead of 50 lines, like this

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {

   fiftyGetters.get_ + i // 

}
```

How can I achieve this in XBase/XText?

Comment: Store pointer to these methods in an array and invoke them on the actual object.

Comment: this wont be possible as of now. maybe you can use closures instead of methods

Comment: (and you can call them via reflection of course)

Comment: How can I use reflection in XBase? I'm new to the language

Comment: dont understand. basically as in java

Comment: but i am not sure if i exactly understand why 50 calls are a problem for you

Comment: It's not just 1 time I have to call 50 methods haha. So I prefer to do it in a loop